# How to install packer system-wide?

Tags: filesystem

Where can I install [packer](https://www.packer.io/) in filesystem for system-wide usage in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial? Where should I place its binary to be available system-wide since it is not part of the OS?

Comment: `packer` is a _single_ binary, so there isn't really anything to install. You can place it anywhere that is convenient such as any directory on your `$PATH`. I would recommend putting it in `~/bin`.

Comment: Where is the correct location for third-party binaries that are not part of the OS(Ubuntu)?

Comment: I would put it in /opt and then link it from /usr/bin

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto there is seldom a "right" position for anything. Put it where you want an either link it to a folder in your $PATH or change your $PATH to add the folder where it is contained :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied binary to **/usr/local/bin**.

This location is for normal user programs not managed by the distribution package manager, e.g. locally compiled packages. This prevents these softwares from being deleted when system upgrades. This usage is the *de facto* convention. As was said in comments, there is not an unique location for copying packer binary to.

Also, this path is already in the *$PATH* environment variable.